# Summarize when a field is zero

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question about Oracle SQL. I have 3 fields need to calc.

[image]

**Current code**:

```
CASE
WHEN SUM(marketingid) = 0 THEN nvl(COUNT(DISTINCT sessionid),0)
ELSE nvl(COUNT(DISTINCT marketingid),0)
END AS count
```

But it does not seem right. Please kindly help. Thank you!

Comment: The column names in the image do not match the column names in the "current code". Which one is it?

Comment: 3+3+3+2 add up to 11, though your sample data shows 10 rows.

Comment: Are you wanting to preserve two different rows for ID 8991620181025 like you have in rows 1/3 of the results?  If so then this is also an island and gap problem.  To handle this we need to know what field your order by to preserve the ID gap.  Since we don't know what field this is; i'm going to say we can't do it as session ID doesn't appear to be the sorted value.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields...

Answer (score 0):

Given the data you've posted so far, it sounds like you could rephrase your question as simply asking the counts over the number of distinct groups of `id`, `marketingid`, and `sessionid` in `your_table`:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count,
       CASE WHEN MAX(marketingid)=0 AND MIN(marketingid)=0
            THEN 'count(distinct sessionid)'
            ELSE 'count(distinct marketingid)' END AS methodology 
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY id, marketingid, sessionid
```

That query should produce precisely the result table you posted.